# Putting ul inside borders of website skeleton in html

Tags: html, web

So I'm taking a crack at building my first website and am running into some issues. I would like my navigation bar to be inside the "borders" of the skeleton of the website. I have my navigation bar inside the tags of the skeleton, so I don't understand why it's appearing like this..
[image]

here's my code
http://pastebin.com/jZ2KhaNx
http://pastebin.com/Zt88VUe6

Comment: pls provide stylesheet.css

Comment: create fiddle on jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Dom doesn't line 21 close off the header div?

Comment: #skeleton {
      padding-top: 1em;
      /* background-color: #F3F3DD;  */
      border: .5em double blue;
      padding: .5em;

      -moz-border-radius: 2em;
      border-radius: 2em; /* covers safari */

      -moz-box-shadow: 3em 3em 10em rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
      -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.5) 3em 3em 10em;
    }

    #navigation {
      /*float: left;*/
      margin-right: 2em;
      margin-left: 1em;
      margin-top: 2em;
      margin-bottom: 1em;
      width: 12em;
      font-size: .95em;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you replace your CSS with this

```
#skeleton {
  padding-top: 1em;
  border: .5em double blue;
  padding: .5em;
  -moz-border-radius: 2em;
  border-radius: 2em;
  -moz-box-shadow: 3em 3em 10em rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.5) 3em 3em 10em;
}

#navigation {
  margin-right: 2em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  width: 12em;
  font-size: .95em;
}

#navigation {
    float: left;
    height:300px;
}

#content{
    float: left;
    height:300px;
}
```

Create a div as follows after navigation

```
<div id="content">
    <p>
        bla bla bla bla blaba alblalljjlahy
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked! thanks! Could you please explain why the float: left would cause it to not appear in the skeleton?

Comment: floating makes the navigation div to float towards left.. unless you give a fixed height to a floated div . it will floated above the parant link ...

Comment: but wouldn't that make it float to the left *inside the skeleton?

Comment: i cant understand what you say...i made some edits to previous comment lets check it...@ComputerDope

Comment: I want to make the list appear all the way to the left (besides the margins), inside the skeleton. I then want to have a paragraph to the right of the list, still inside the skeleton. Thats why i need the float left

Comment: you can un comment float left and provide a fixed height to navigation... this also works fine...

Comment: I had float left there because I want the nav bar to always be on the left. I want everything else I'm about to add to be on the right. Now, when I add a paragraph/heading it appears below it. how do i make it appear to the right of it now, with float commented out??

Answer (score 0):

My method is unconventional but I never liked the idosychroncies and Browser incompatibilities associated with  a `ul>` `<a>` nav menu.

Most solutions require inline-block where a few years ago it was a much bigger isue that today.  But still there are many Browsers that do not handle inline-block.

I like to use `<button>` in places where a div is typically used.  The reason being its default display is the same as inline-block.

I also find wrapping an element with a `<form>` to be quite handy as it does not affect page rendering when giving it display:inline.  Additionally you can add parameters to an element contained within a form with the `

In this case I would make each nav link a form with a `<button type="submit">`.  Buttons are very easy to style and they naturally render side by side.  Or the can be stacked with a `<br/>`

So my nav row would look something like this:

```
<div id="nav">
<form action="link"><button type="submit">Link Text</button></form>
<form action="link"><button type="submit">Link Text</button></form>
<form action="link"><button type="submit">Link Text</button></form>
<form action="link"><button type="submit">Link Text</button></form>
</div>
```

**This works with almost no CSS required.**

And there is a lot you can do by adding hidden inputs.